# Is there any python code for CreditGrades model?

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for any existing code for CreditGrades model.
Any python code is OKAY.
Also, I will need numeric differentiation for hedge ratio. 
Any suggestion on numeric differentiation in python.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Google landed me here, did you find any CreditGrades python modules (after all those years;) ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can try Symbolic differentiation. Also I can use SymPy with NumPy.